# How to pass array of doubles from c# to c++ via DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dllimport, unmanaged

I have a c++ function with the method signature as

```
MyMethod(std::vector<double> tissueData, std::vector<double> BGData, std::vector<double> TFData, std::vector<double> colMeans, std::vector<double> colStds, std::vector<double> model)
```

I wish to call this c++ function in c# via dllimport. While creating the dll library I have defined the function from the c++ side as

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyMethod(double *tissue, double *bg, double *tf, double *colMeans, double *colStds, double* model);
```

I plan to pass an array of doubles from the c# side to the c++ dll function. 
However, I am not sure how I should define the DllImport from the c# side and also how should i convert the double array when i parse it into the dllImport function ?

I read a little about marshalling but i still dont quite get it and Im not sure if it can be applied here ?

Comment: You can't call the from outside C++ code. You need to use a function that accepts as parameters a pointer to the first element of each array, and the length of each array.

Comment: What do u mean ? I have not defined the dllimport attribute in the c# code

Comment: I'm confused. What is the function with std::vector doing in the question? Also, the function with `double*`, how can that function know the array length? As for the pinvoke, use `double[]` to map to `double*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot interop with C++ classes (such as `std::vector`), only with basic C-style data types and pointers. (As a side note) that was one of the problems Microsoft attempted to solve when it invented COM.

To make it work, you should export a different function, which receives plain C arrays and their respective lengths:

#### C++ side

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyExternMethod(
    double *tissue, int tissueLen, 
    double *bg, int bgLen,
    /* ... the rest ... */
);

// implementation
int MyExternMethod(
    double* tissue, int tissueLen, 
    double* bg, int bgLen,
    /* ... the rest ... */ )
{
    // call your original method from here:

    std::vector<double> tissueData(tissue, tissue + tissueLen);
    std::vector<double> bgData(bg, bg + bgLen);
    /* ... the rest ... */

    return MyMethod(tissueData, bgData, /* ...the rest... */);
}
```

The interop import on C# side would be:

#### C# side

```cs
public static class MyLibMethods
{
    [DllImport("MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int MyExternMethod(
        double[] tissue, int tissueLen,
        double[] bg, int bgLen,
        /*...the rest...*/
    );
}
```

And you can call it in C# like this:

#### C# side

```cs
public int CallMyExternMethod(double[] tissue, double[] bg, /*... the rest ...*/)
{
    return MyLibMethods.MyExternMethod(
        tissue, tissue.Length,
        bg, bg.Length,
        /*...the rest...*/
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think that was really the main driving force behind COM, but that's another story. This code omits the calling convention however. The C++ code uses cdecl.

Comment: Good catch @DavidHeffernan, fixed both of the issues you mentioned